# Desktop freeze and then reboot itself, happens randomly

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, cpu, gpu

Have upgrade a desktop with a few hardware a while ago, and it starts randomly(After a few hours of using) completely frozen a few seconds and then reboot itself.

It probably not an OS problem:
Happened to window10, then switch to ubuntu20.04 then ubuntu18.04, happens to all of them,

It's probably not a software problem:
Happens when play games, Visual Studio, or any other software. (Notice happens when moving cursor over the edge of a software/system dialog a few times)

when check by command 'last':

[image]
Dec 14:31 was when it happens, it just says it reboot, rather than crash (No idea what crashed in 12:49)

Did a memtest, not throw any error:

[image]

My hardware:

[image]

Note: I did try to run a mining script 24/7 for several days without connect monitor/mice/keyboard. And it runs well without reboot itself.

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: This is incredibly vague.If you can provide the system logs that show what is taking place at the time of reboot, it may be possible to better determine what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a thermal problem? Try monitoring the temperature of CPU and GPU. You can use the `sensors` command from the *lm-sensors* package; if you have an NVidia graphics card, there is `nvidia-smi` from the *nvidia-utils* package.

Good old opening the computer case and cleaning out dust puppies may help; also check if all the fans are working.